# Setting up SPF, DKIM and Sender ID with Google Cloud DNS, G Suite and WHM / cPanel Server

Tags: spf, dkim, google-cloud-dns, dmarc, sender-id

I just migrated to a new server (CENTOS 6.8 x86_64 virtuozzo – vps1909  WHM 58.0 (build 37)). I decided to use Google Cloud DNS instead to manage my DNS zones instead of WHM.

I'm having a really hard time setting up email via G Suite for all my domains using Google Cloud DNS. The problem comes when setting up DKIM, SPF and Sender ID.

1. DKIM is a pain, because it's too long for Google Cloud DNS, where and how do you split it ? Do you add " for each line ? [current setup here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVBtp.png)
2. If I want an SPF record that allows G Suite and my server (via PHP) to send emails from @mydomain.com, how do I setup that ? (Current setup : "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all")
3. All the regular G Suite DNS info are in there :

**THE MX**

```
1 aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
5 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
10 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
```

**All those CNAME**

```
mail > ghs.google.com.
calendar > ghs.google.com.
drive > ghs.google.com.
sites > ghs.google.com.
groups > ghs.google.com.
```

I need information on how to setup all those SPF, DKIM, DMARC, PTR properly ... I'm not looking for something hyper-secure, just something that works and won't fall into spam or just plain bounce ...

Comment: Were you able to set up the Cloud DNS records ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's no reason to black out any part of your Public DKIM Key. You should also be able to do it as just 1 string. If it's greater then 512 characters that's when it becomes a problem.

You SPF record will be:

`v=spf1 mx a include:_spf.google.com ~all` - Which states allow all your MX and A records to send.

To learn how to set up everything go here: https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/ then click on blogs --> How to Setup

Comment: When I add the full string, I get invalid record data

Comment: Depending on you interface you might need to put the whole thing in double quotes